# How to find a globally unique thread/conversation ID in gmail?

Tags: google-api, gmail

I'm trying to find a unique ID in Gmail that identifies a thread which may have many replies from different users.
I tried to look for ThreadID but it seems it is differet for different users.

I've tested the following scenario:

- user A sends an email to user B
- user B replies (essentially creating a thread).

Now I'd expect the thread ID to be the same for both users but it isnt.

In my case the thread ID for user A was `18a89510c1efe95a` (data-legacy-thread-id="18a89510c1efe95a")
and the thread ID for user B was `18a8950c918b58b8` (data-legacy-thread-id="18a8950c918b58b8")

I also experimented with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.threads/list) by retrieving the list of threads of user A and then the list of threads of user B and it is the same result: for the same conversation where these users are part of, the thread IDs seem to be different.

I've lost many hours and I'm not getting anywhere. Is there any globally unique ID for the conversation, meaning the thread of email replies?

The following would be my use-case:

- user A opens the email thread and writes some note.
- user B opens the email thread to reply and he can see the note that use A left.

but I can't do this because currently user A and B seem to have different threadIDs for the same conversation.

Not sure if I was able to explain clear enough and give enough context.